# Cmap w/ line plot. Can either plot under line (but solid) or gradient (but over line)

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization, gradient

I am trying a visualization problem based off of a dataset processed with pandas and matplotlib. I plotted the data in a line plot.  My goal is to have the area underneath the curve be gradient-ed with cmap (ex 'plasma')

However, both of my best attempts are wrong for different reasons. The first will color with a gradient, but only over the line. The second will color under the line, but only with a solid color. I have been stuck for a very long time... Thank you!

```
ax = plot_chance_death.plot(kind='line', x = 'State', y = 'Percent Chance', 
ax=ax, color='indigo')
l1 = ax.lines[0]
x1 = l1.get_ydata()
y1 = l1.get_xdata()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot only the outline of the polygon, and capture the result
poly, = ax.fill(x1, y1, facecolor='none')

# get the extent of the axes
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()

# create a dummy image
img_data = np.arange(ymin,ymax,(ymax-ymin)/100.)
img_data = img_data.reshape(img_data.size,1)

# plot and clip the image
im = ax.imshow(img_data, aspect='auto',  origin='upper', cmap='plasma', 
extent=[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax], vmin=1., vmax=y1.max())

#this shows the gradient but above the line
im.set_clip_path(poly)

###this solution colors underneath but solid color
ax.fill_between(x1, y1, y2=0, cmap='plasma',  norm=(0,.5))
```

[image: Link to Image Here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense to include the bottom of the region to use as clip_path into the `Path`. You may create the `Path` from a `plot` of the data and then add the two bottom points to it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path

df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : np.linspace(0,0.05,40),
                   "y" : np.cumsum(np.random.rand(40))[::-1]*3})


fig, ax = plt.subplots()


l, = ax.plot(df.x, df.y, color="k")

# get the extent of the axes
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()

# create a dummy image
img_data = np.arange(ymin,ymax,(ymax-ymin)/100.)
img_data = img_data.reshape(img_data.size,1)

# plot and clip the image
im = ax.imshow(img_data, aspect='auto',  origin='upper', cmap='plasma', 
               extent=[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax], vmin=1., vmax=df.y.max())

px,py = l.get_data()

p0 = [[px[-1], py.min()], [px[0], py.min()]]
p = np.concatenate((np.c_[px,py],p0))
path = Path(p)

im.set_clip_path(path, transform=ax.transData)

plt.show()
```

[image]